# Forms inside Elm-ui

Tags: html, forms, elm

I need to insert `<form>` into the DOM. Otherwise password managers like LastPass doesn't work and you cannot submit it by hitting enter on your keyboard. I could not find a better way than converting whole content of `<form>` to `Html msg` from `Element msg` and back again. This is really inefficient.

```
insertForm : List (Element msg) -> Element msg
insertForm elements =
    html
        (Html.form []
            [ layout []
                (column [] elements)
            ]
        )
```

I'm sure there must be a better way. But I could not find it anywhere in [elm-ui docs](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/mdgriffith/elm-ui/latest/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search the elm-ui repo for "form" and look through the code, you will find that `Html.form` is not invoked.

Therefore, the way to do it is as you have shown, which is to use `Element.html`.

You claim "This is really inefficient.". That claim is false. elm-ui must store a representation of `Element` internally, then convert that to `elm/html`'s Html at the end. There is nothing inefficient about wrapping and storing `Html` directly and outputting it at the end. That's actually the least amount of work elm-ui has to do, because you've already done the work of generating the actual `Html` you want.